# Spotipy remove_all_occurerences only works half the time

Tags: python, spotipy

```
currently_playing = sp.current_user_playing_track()
time_elapsed = currently_playing['progress_ms'] / 1000 / 60
try:
    if time_elapsed < 0.5:
        last_song_played = sp.current_user_recently_played(1)
        sp.playlist_remove_all_occurrences_of_items(playlist_id=playlisturi, 
        items={last_song_played['items'][0]['track']['uri']})
    else:
        sp.playlist_remove_all_occurrences_of_items(playlist_id=playlisturi, 
        items={currently_playing['item']['uri']})
```

The method playlist_remove_all_occurrences_of_items() works in the else-block but not in the if-block.

I did try to debug the code and in both blocks Spotipy gets a 200 response-Code from Spotify, but the one is deleting the the songs, the other is not. Maybe I'm just blind.

*Edit
Okay, maybe found the source of the error. If the song I want to delete is not played long enough(this is a guess), the current_user_recently_played is not updated. So it tries to delete the already Deleted track and "successful". If i let a song run for the full length it gets update, because i tried to test as fast as possible and just let a song play for a few seconds before skipping, the current_user_recently_played was not updated

Answer (score 0):

The `current_user_playing_track()` is intuitively easy to understand.
It returns to the currently playing song.

But the `current_user_recently_played()` has a little confusing.

When the song I just heard transitioned to the next track from A to B song.
`current_user_recently_played(1)` returns Song A.

It means `Song A` has finished passing the end of the progress bar.
And to go move next song B,

Song A

[image]

Song B

[image]

This demo code is easy to figure out during your play song by Spotify Web GUI
next your code.

demo.py

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id = '<your client ID>',
    client_secret= '<your client secret>',
    redirect_uri='<your client call back URL>',
    scope='user-read-currently-playing,user-read-recently-played'))

def Get_Both_Song():
    last_song_played = sp.current_user_recently_played(limit=1)
    print("last_song_played " , last_song_played['items'][0]['track']['name'], ",", last_song_played['items'][0]['track']['uri'],"played_at: ", last_song_played['items'][0]['played_at'])

    currently_playing = sp.current_user_playing_track()
    print("currently_playing ", currently_playing['item']['name'], ",", currently_playing['item']['uri'])

Get_Both_Song()
```

[image]

Back to your code in If true case (form start to half time)

`sp.current_user_recently_played(1)` return whatever finished song before the current playing song.

The `playlist_remove_all_occurrences_of_items()` straightforward remove by the track ID parameter.
And print() will show to confirm which song returned from `current_user_recently_played()`.

```
    if time_elapsed < 0.5:
        last_song_played = sp.current_user_recently_played(1)
        print("last_song_played " , last_song_played['items'][0]['track']['name'], ",", last_song_played['items'][0]['track']['uri'],"played_at: ", last_song_played['items'][0]['played_at'])
```